# Match number with special character next to it

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that can look in different ways.

```
$str = "11:00 Team1 - Team2 0-0"
$str = "4' Team1 - Team2 2-1"
$str = "Half time Team1 - Team2 2-1"
$str = "55' Team1 - Team2 3-1"
$str = "Finished Team1 - Team2 2-1"
```

By using regex, I would like to know when the string contains "Number+:+Number", "Number+'" and none of the two previous combinations. Furthermore I would like to extract "Number+-+Number".

I've tried this for the 2nd example:

```
preg_match("/[0-9+']/", $str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**These are the regular expressions you need:**

For the first: (Number + : + Number)

```
/[0-9]+:[0-9]+/
```

For the second: (Number + ')

```
/[0-9]+'/
```

For the third: (Number + - + Number)

```
/[0-9]+-[0-9]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ret = preg_match_all('/^([0-9]+\'|:)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($ret) // 0 for no match, 1 for match
```

Comment: You are already assigning the matches to `$matches`. No need to put it into `$ret` as well.

Comment: $ret returns the RESULT of preg_match (eg true|false), $matches is the array of actual matches found.

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression to match all cases would be

```
\d+[:'-]\d*
```

It matches one or more digits, then either a colon, ' or dash, then zero or more digits.

PHP example

```
$str[] = "11:00 Team1 - Team2 0-0";
$str[] = "4' Team1 - Team2 2-1";
$str[] = "Half time Team1 - Team2 2-1";
$str[] = "55' Team1 - Team2 3-1";
$str[] = "Finished Team1 - Team2 2-1";

foreach($str as $s) {
    preg_match_all("/\d+[:'-]\d*/", $s, $res);
    print_r($res);
}
```

prints

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 11:00 [1] => 0-0 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4' [1] => 2-1 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2-1 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 55' [1] => 3-1 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2-1 ) )
```

[Live fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6i7-hps)